# Problem with understanding homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the group of all matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b \\
        0 & 1 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, also known as Heisenberg group.

I defined a function $f: G \rightarrow (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R,+)$, and the action being: $f( \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b \\
        0 & 1 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix})=(a,c)$ and tried proving $f$ is a homomorphism.

$f(\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a_1 & b_1 \\
        0 & 1 & c_1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
        0 & 1 & c_2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix})=f(\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a_1+a_2 & b_1+a_1c_2+b_2 \\
        0 & 1 & c_1+c_2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix})=(a_1+a_2,c_1+c_2)=(a_1,c_1)+(a_2,c_2)$

The problem I have is with the last step. I think I got something wrong with my understanding, but don't I have to say $f$ is injective in order for me being able to link, for instance $(a_1,c_1)$ with $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a_1 & b_1 \\
        0 & 1 & c_1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Yeah, thank you - as usual :]

Comment: Homomorphisms don't have to be injective. Obviously your homomorphism won't be, because it loses information about $b$.

Comment: Now, what's the problem again? What are you trying to prove? The function $\;f\;$ is obviously not injective, as for fixed $\;a,c\;$ and **any** $\;b\;$ you get the same imagen...so what's the problem with the last step?

Comment: I have answered below but I think the problem is a misunderstanding between thinking that it is required to prove that $(a_1,c_1)$ can ONLY come from that one particular matrix. This is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have proved, using the first isomophism theorem, is that

$$G/\ker f\cong\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;\ker f=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b \\
        0 & 1 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\in G\;\;:\;\;\;a=c=0\right\}$$

Comment: That was my intention in building that homomorphism (part of a homework). [and that $kerf=Z(\mathbb H_3)]$ Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @charlie....but, what do you call $\;\Bbb H_3\;$ to??

Comment: Sorry, that's $G$, $\mathbb H$ as the Heisenberg group

Comment: Oh, I see...I'm used to focus on positive characteristic when talking of the Heisenberg group....

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct and you proved it is a group homomorphism. What you have is that $f$ "forgets" $b$, i.e. $f(A)=f(B)$ if and only if $a_{A}=a_{B}$ and $c_{A}=c_{B}$. In more precise terms, you have that $ker(f)=\lbrace \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)|b \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$

Answer (score 0):

You definitely KNOW that $f\left(\left( \begin{matrix} 1& a_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 1 & c_1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)\right) = (a_1,c_1)$ and that is all you were after.

Injectivity only stops anything else being mapped onto $(a_1,c_1)$...